# Chromedriver error on jenkins

Tags: jenkins, robotframework, selenium-chromedriver, selenium2library

i jave set up a jenkins project that would run our robot tests. Our robot tests are creating using selenium2library. since we are going to run the test on Chrome, i have downloaded the ChromeDriver and set it up in the test. that was a month ago and everything was working. but now, when i run the project, i get this error on the Open Browser keyword:

> WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: unable to discover open
>   pages   (Driver info: chromedriver=2.23.409699
>   (49b0fa931cda1caad0ae15b7d1b68004acd05129),platform=Windows NT
>   6.3.9600 x86_64)

i did some research and some people got around with it by passing the no-sandbox argument. but i cannot find anything on how to pass the argument in selenium2library. i tried this but it is not working:

```
Open Browser   www.hello.com   Chrome   no-sandbox
```

im hoping someone can help me. thanks!

specs:
  selenium2library - 1.7.4
  chrome (in the jenkins server) - Version 52.0.2743.116 m
  chromedriver - 2.23

edit:
  this is where i found out about the no-sandbox thing. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/selenium-users/gfvfH-YEC48

Comment: Just from looking at [the source](https://github.com/robotframework/Selenium2Library/blob/ec3c897935866b62a64c311bc3218c2538ba1278/src/Selenium2Library/keywords/_browsermanagement.py): For `create_webdriver` it states: 
_Like 'Open Browser', but allows passing arguments to a WebDriver's \_\_init\_\_. \_Open Browser\_ is preferred over \_Create Webdriver\_ when feasible._

Comment: can someone close this? my issue got resolved but im not sure how. i used chromedriver 2.21 then it worked. then i switched to 2.23 (latest version) and it worked as well.